# Android App Null Pointer on Specific Textview

Tags: android, android-layout

Normally null pointer exceptions seem to be view related - where the wrong layout is targeted.

This is different I reckon.  I have four textviews in a layout and one returns a null, the rest work fine.  Here is the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="hello" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="stringello2" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ip"
        android.id="@+id/iptest"
    />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="hostname" 
        android:id="@+id/hostname"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

And here is the test code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    protected TextView text;
    protected TextView ip;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        text.setText("goodbye");
        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hostname);
        text.setText("hostname flibble");
    //  text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text2);
        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.iptest);
        text.setText("ip flibble");
    }
}
```

If I switch the comment to the other textview, it works fine.  If I target `iptest` it returns null and raises an exception.

Any ideas why?  All four appear in `gen` and they all reappear if I delete `gen` and recompile.

Answer (score 5):

in your TextView Tag

```
 <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ip"
        android.id="@+id/iptest"
    />
```

you had taken a *.(dot)* instead of *:(colon)*

```
 android.id="@+id/iptest"
```

shoulb de like this

```
 android:id="@+id/iptest"
```

Moreover please clean your project regularly.

Comment: What do you mean by "clean" that isn't done by deleting `gen`?

Comment: I can't believe I missed that colon :)

Comment: Ahh, you are referring to the Eclipse "clean"?  I am not using eclipse.

Comment: @ Paul which IDE you using then?

Comment: @vnshetty AIDE at the moment, the android app

Answer (score 1):

your R class is not holding iptest reference . android.id="@+id/iptest" is wrong . It should be android:id